# Apache Wicket DateTextField clear

Tags: apache, date, wicket

I have a problem in my DateTextField in Wicket. I want to set it by default to nothing, null, so date can be choosed after someone picks it. But by default it sets value to current day. How to "clear" it so nothing is in this datetextfield? Here is my Datefield code:

```
DateField date_insert_date_from = new DateField("insert_date_from", new PropertyModel(this, "date")) {

        /**
         * Format date to yyyy-MM-dd pattern.
         */
        @Override
        protected DateTextField newDateTextField(String id, PropertyModel dateFieldModel) {
            return DateTextField.forDatePattern(id, dateFieldModel, "yyyy-MM-dd");
        }
    };
    form.add(date_insert_date_from);
```

Comment: show your model's `this.date` definition. Does it have `null` in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @kan says, you need to make sure the modelobject for the datefield is `null`.

Simple way to do so is:

```
DateField date_insert_date_from = new DateField("insert_date_from", new Model<Date>(null));
```

Now, if anyone enters a date into the datefield and submits the form, the Model will contain the chosen date and you can retrieve it by writing:

```
Date chosenDate = date_insert_date_from.getModelObject();
```

If you want to use a propertymodel, as you do, you need to make sure the object on which the propertymodel acts (`this` in your case) has a field capable of holding a date and getter/setter methods for that field.

In your case, `this.date` should be initialized with `null` and `this` should have

```
public Date getDate()
```

and

```
public void setDate(Date date)
```

methods.